# Add SimpleMarkerSymbol and then remove it upon next click

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

My map has some markers and when I click to identify a marker, I'm adding a marker to it.  When I click the next marker though, I'd like for the previous marker to be removed since I'm only interested in the more recently identified element.

I'm using the legacy modules, JavaScript API.

```
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 18,
        new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
        new dojo.Color([0,0,0]), 1),        // border color
        new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.80]));  // fill color
    App.map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(queryResults[0].feature.geometry, symbol));
```

Comment: I'm very new to the arcgis stuff so if my terms are not used correctly, please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.  The map marker is coming from the map service/layer.  The marker I'm adding is simply a square symbol to indicate which marker received the mouse click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like `map.graphics.clear()`   (It your case it looks like it may need to be `App.map.graphics.clear()` but you can put it in context of your code.)  But you can call a `.clear()` method on the graphics layer in the map to clear all the graphics.  If you just want to remove specific graphics without removing all of them, that would require other steps, such as saving a reference to each individual graphic and then deleting them individually as needed.  But if you're just trying to clear and add a new marker each time, just use the `.clear()` method.

More details on working with graphics at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_graphics.html

Comment: The `App.map.graphics.clear()` is just what I needed.  I was in the process of reading about the `.clear()` method when your answer came in which was spot-on.  Thank you.